# Getting the maximum date in a dataframe Pandas does not return the maximum

Tags: python, pandas, date

I am trying to extract the most recent date from a dataframe pandas.

I have a fairly simple line of code which seems to be the recommended way from many sources online

```
maxdate = df['DATE'].max()
maxdate
'31/12/2021'
```

However I know my dataframe contains a record of '11/09/2022'.  Is the issue to do with the date format?  I don't want to change the date format as it will impact on my other things

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the column values to `pd.to_datetime` function, then take the index for maximum value, and get the `DATE` value at that index, this way, you'll get the maximum `DATE` without having to modify existing column.

```py
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], dayfirst=True).idxmax(), 'DATE']
```

Comment: thanks unfortunately that returned '12/08/2022' which is still not the most recent date

Comment: Try passing `dayfirst=True` , see the updated answer